# Boost library RNG output behaving strangely when stored in an object

Tags: c++, object, boost, double

I'm trying to use the boost library to generate random numbers. First I used the boost library to make this very simple class:

```
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_01.hpp>

class TimeRNG01 {

private:
    boost::random::mt19937 rng;
    boost::random::uniform_01<double> roll;
public:
    TimeRNG01(){
        unsigned int t = static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0));
        rng.seed(t);
    }

    double num(){return roll(rng);}
};
```

I then made this even simpler class to test it out in an object:

```
class Thingy {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Thingy(double x){set_x(x);}
    void set_x(int x){ this->x = x; }
    double get_x(){return x;}
};
```

In my main method, I was getting some weird results, so I tried a few things to debug it. First, I defined a TimeRNG01 object called trng. Then I wrote:

```
double q = trng.num();
cout << q << endl;
```

which prints a random number between 0 and 1, exactly as expected. But when I next tried to store that q in a Thingy, I got something weird:

```
Thingy t(q);
cout << t.get_x() << endl;
```

This always prints 0, and not the random number, which is unexpected. To make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong with the Thingy class, I tried this:

```
double f = 1;
Thingy r(f);
cout << r.get_x() << endl;
```

which prints 1, exactly as expected.

So for some reason, it seems that the output of this random number generator is not treated as a normal double, and doesn't store  in objects correctly. How can I rectify this so that q is able to be stored as the x value of Thingy?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of truncation from `double` to `int`. Your `set_x` takes an `int` as parameter, but you're passing in a `double` uniformly distributed in `[0,1)`, hence the argument is converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing a double into the constructor but the
set function takes an int:

```
Thingy(double x){set_x(x);}
void set_x(int x){ this->x = x; }//Sure you want to take an int in parameter here?
```

This might be causing a conversion you don't want.

Because x is always in the range [0,1) the double becomes the int 0 all the time.

Also worth mentioning, if you have c++11 available you might be able to remove your dependency on boost. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random for more information on that.